# Совет по организации хранения БД

Tags: sql, sql-server

Можете подсказать как правильно организовать БД на MsSQL, где файл .mdf весит около 100 ГБ и .ldf около 1 ТБ? Я посмотрел несколько [статей](http://sqlcom.ru/dba-tools/manage-disk-queue/?ysclid=lhondk4jfl948037434) и использовал IOPS [калькулятор](https://www.team.ru/RAID-IOPS-Calculator.php) и к сожалению растерялся в правильном выборе организации (Хранение и быстрое развёртывание после сбоев) работы с БД. Соотношение чтение/записи в БД примерно 40%/60%. БД разрастается со средней скоростью (Примерно 1-5 МБ в сутки. Замер шёл в течении двух недель). Примерная нагрузка БД - 200 IOPS.

1. Какой лучше использовать Raid массив?
2. Как хранить БД? То есть, стоит ли лог транзакции и саму БД хранить на одном Raid масиве/логическом разделе?
3. Можно ли подсоединить к старому бэкапу БД более новый файл транзакции (Не бэкап, а именно .ldf файл)? Например есть живой .ldf файл новые данные, но в бэкапе .mdf файла их нет. Как восстановить БД с подгрузкой данных из живого .ldf файла?
4. Какой лучший способ быстрого развёртывания БД после сбоя?

Мои мысли:

1. Я остановился на Raid 10.
2. Почитав про [Настройка и планирование загрузки SQL Server и хранилища](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sharepoint/administration/storage-and-sql-server-capacity-planning-and-configuration) , пришёл к выводу что лучше хранить на разных разделах/Raid массиве.
3. Сколько читал и пробовал, ничего не получилось... Думаю стоит делать полный бэкап БД ежедневно, но это плохой вариант и не рационально по отношению к месту на сетевом хранилище.
4. Особо статей не нашёл. Можете посоветовать информацию и реальные примеры?

Менять MsSQL на другой тип хранения БД нельзя по некоторым внутренним причинам.

Comment: Выполните бекап лога транзакций и после этого шринк файла лога. Лог транзакций не должен быть больше данных, тем более в 10 раз. В дальнейшем необходимо выполнять бекап лога транзакций на регулярной основе

Comment: 4 пункт - `Replication`, путем переброски с master на slave. Но это возможно если есть лишние мощности под резервную СУБД. Ну или еще варианты - `Mirroring`, либо `Transaction Log Shipping`.

Comment: @DenisRubashkin, это не реальные данные, так как к сожалению не могу указать настоящие...

Comment: @Arkee, есть два сервера примерно одинаковой мощности. Оба допустим на Raid 10 где 4 диска SATA на 7200.